# Verifing a File with gpg gives exit code 0, even when the key has no trusted signature

Tags: gnupg

I'm trying to verify a signature with `pgp`. I want to check only for trusted keys.

```
gpg --verify MyFile.text ; echo $?
```

This gives me some output like (if the key is not a trusted one):

```
gpg: Good signature from "Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>" 
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature! 
gpg: There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
```

and the exit code of gpg is 0

How can I tell gpg to give an exit code != 0, if there is a signature of an untrusted key **or** a bad signature?

Answer (score 0):

Myself an answer. I think it's not really optimal and secure. But it's working.

I encapsulated the verify part into a separate bash script file:

```
#/bin/bash    
LANG=C LC_MESSAGES=C gpg --verify $1 2>&1 | grep WARNING > /dev/null
if [[ "${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]}" == "0 1" ]]; then
  exit 0
else
  exit 1
fi
```